# Extjs - Parent component's listener is not triggered from children

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have just started to write Ext and i already have some issues. Please keep in mind that i'm currently learning the framework.

I have 2 views.

The view A has button with a listener

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'test',
iconCls: 'x-fa fa-search',
margin: '30px 0 10px 2px',
action: 'test',   
listeners: {
    click: 'refreshGrids'
}
```

The view B extends view A and also does a parent call

```
this.callParent();
```

So now the button is available in both views.

In my Controller i have the following function

```
refreshGrids: function(obj){
    console.log(obj)
}
```

The problem is that from the view A i can normally see the log while pressing the button, but in view B i can not since the method is never called.

Now, if i instead of using a method in the controller, i use a callback in the `click` event, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include a small example of the A, B components and where they are added?

Comment: Honestly speaking there is not much going on. I'm just defining the view A which extends: 'Ext.form.FieldSet' and view B which extends view A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having view B extend A where A has a controller is relatively easy in ExtJS 6.

You can run the following code here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

Make sure to set the version to version 6.x (e.g. 6.7.0), because version 7.x is live.

Here is a live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/352k

```js
/** @filename ./BaseController.js */
Ext.define('com.stackoverflow.BaseController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias: 'controller.base',
  refreshGrids: function() {
    var view = this.getView();
    var className = view.__proto__.$className;
    var suffix = view.getButtonTextSuffix();
    Ext.Msg.alert(className, 'Refreshing grids for... ' + suffix);
  }
});

/** @filename ./ViewA.js */
Ext.define('com.stackoverflow.ViewA', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
  alias: 'widget.viewa',
  controller: 'base',

  config: {
    buttonTextSuffix: 'A'
  },

  initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    this.items = {
      xtype: 'button',
      text: 'Test' + ' ' + this.getButtonTextSuffix(),
      iconCls: 'x-fa fa-search',
      margin: '30px 0 10px 2px',
      action: 'test',
      listeners: {
        click: 'refreshGrids'
      }
    };

    me.callParent();
  }
});

/** @filename ./ViewB.js */
Ext.define('com.stackoverflow.ViewB', {
  extend: 'com.stackoverflow.ViewA',
  alias: 'widget.viewb',
  buttonTextSuffix: 'B',
  initComponent: function() {
    // Unless you want to do anything else here, this is unessesary.
    this.callParent();
  }
});

/** @filename ./App.js */
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
      layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
      },
      defaults: {
        flex: 1,
        border: true
      },
      items: [{
        xtype: 'viewa'
      }, {
        xtype: 'viewb'
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, my problem was that i did not add the controller config in my View A. Thanks!